# Save a div as a photo?

Tags: php, javascript, html

So what I want to do is have a div on the page saved to the user's device as an image, is that possible?

for example, lets say I have a div like this:

```
<div id="box"><h3>im a box</h3></div>
```

and I want this div to be captured and saved to the user's computer when he clicks a button on my website

and if that isn't possible then can I save it as something other than an image, like a pdf file.

Comment: you would need to do a post to send the user the "file" since javascript cannot access the client machine.

Comment: i would make use of the gd library in php and generate an image server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you're 100% sure that you need this done client-side then check out http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ It'll take some time integrating this, but it'll work very well in the end.

Comment: but that doesn't allow me to download the image

Comment: Sure it does. Just present it and allow him to save it.